# Como Chamar um Relatório Jaspersoft que tem um SubReport

Tags: java, netbeans, jaspersoft-studio

Bom dia pessoal, sou novo nessa área de fórum e tbm na de programação. Estou criando um pequeno sistema para uma empresa que trabalho, nela a menina do financeiro protocola os boletos hoje na mão e no caderno... queria deixar uma coisa mais automática, então resolvi colocar a mão na massa! Porem agora estou criando um relatório para ela que contem um sub-relatora, no Previwer do jaspersoft ele funciona, mas quando tempo chamar ele no java não consigo. Serei muito grato para quem puder me ajudar, esse é meu código que eu chamo o relatório.

public void Rel_Titulos_so_Data(final String data){

```
    try {
        final ConectaBanco conn = this.conn;
        ConectaBanco.getConnection();
        this.conn.executaSql("SELECT\n" 
                        +"  protocolar_documentos.razao_social,  SUM(protocolar_documentos.valor_documento),\n" 
                        +"  cad_fornecedor.id,\n" 
                        +"  cad_fornecedor.razao_social,\n" 
                        +"  protocolar_documentos.*\n" 
                        +"  \n" 
                        +"  FROM \n" 
                        +"  protocolar_documentos\n" 
                        +"  LEFT JOIN cad_fornecedor ON \n" 
                        +"  ( cad_fornecedor.id = protocolar_documentos.fornecedor)\n" 
                        +"   \n" 
                        +"  WHERE \n" 
                        +"  protocolar_documentos.data = '"+data+"' GROUP BY protocolar_documentos.razao_social\n" 
                        +"  ORDER BY protocolar_documentos.razao_social");
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Arquivos_Relatorios/Relatorio_Titulos.jasper");
        final JRResultSetDataSource jrRS = new JRResultSetDataSource(this.conn.rs);
        final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, (Map)null, (JRDataSource)jrRS);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    }
    catch (JRException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Passei por este mesmo problema a algumas semanas e nao encontrei nada na internet que me ajudasse de fato, entao criei esta solucao.

```
public static Object printJasper(@NonNull final Collection data,
                                 @NonNull String titulo,
                                 String subReport) throws JRException {

    /*exemplo de codigo para compilar relatorio dentro do codigo
    final String sub = "/jasper/sub.jrxml";
    JasperReport subCompilado = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sub);*/


    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",  new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper", subReport)));

    JasperPrint print  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(String.valueOf(new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper"
            , titulo))),map, buildDatasource(data));

    return exportPdf(print);

}
```

Note que eu uso o "Map" para imputar meu sub-report por parametro (e assim que o Jasper trabalha);

Entao dentro do teu jrxml voce deve ter uma tag desta forma;

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="0" width="553" height="20" uuid="dcb4de43-b64f-4e50-a4b1-5ad31a1cd9a2"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("carga.ordens")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Para este caso estou usando um json como datasource, mas nao deve mudar nada.

Comment: tentei fazer tudo o que vc falou, mas por conta do meu baixo conhecimento não obtive êxito... Muito obrigada pela força vou continuar estudando para ver se consigo fazer com que funcione

Comment: @AllysonHenrique pelo oque eu vi no seu codigo, voce nao esta passando o subreport para o java rodar.

Por mais que dentro do Main (seu relatorio prinicipal) ele esta com o subreport vinculado, quando voce chama o JasperPrint voce deve passar o subreport como parametro.



    `final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("seu main report", "seu sub report", "seu data source");`

Voce deve deixar o jrxml esperando o subreport como parametro, como passei no exemplo a tag subreport esperando um $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}

Comment: voce esta (Map) null, no lugar do subreport, por isto nao roda ;)